# Fn+keys for volume broken after reinstalling alsa/pulseaudio

Tags: troubleshooting

I had no sound in a Kubuntu 18.10 installation and run this:

`apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio && apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio && alsa force-reload`

After it, everything was working, but the `Fn+volumeup/down/mute` combination. I suppose some packages were removed with the above command.

Other Fn+key combinations work fine. Some programs, like smplayer, now grab the Fn+volume key combination and set the volume accordingly. But earlier Fn+vol was for system volume.

How can I get this back as it was? That is, Fn+key for system sound.

Obtained from `xev`:

```
KeyRelease event, serial 42, synthetic NO, window 0x8000001,
    root 0x6a9, subw 0x0, time 1842765, (935,677), root:(935,706),
    state 0x0, keycode 122 (keysym 0x1008ff11, XF86AudioLowerVolume), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 42, synthetic NO, window 0x8000001,
    root 0x6a9, subw 0x0, time 1843182, (935,677), root:(935,706),
    state 0x0, keycode 123 (keysym 0x1008ff13, XF86AudioRaiseVolume), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 42, synthetic NO, window 0x8000001,
    root 0x6a9, subw 0x0, time 1843257, (935,677), root:(935,706),
    state 0x0, keycode 151 (keysym 0x1008ff2b, XF86WakeUp), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Comment: Do you have a log file (e.g. /var/log/dpkg.log) which shows which packages were removed?

Comment: @deltab Yes, I'll see if reinstalling some solves the problem.

Comment: @deltab: indeed, simply searching for remove/purge and reinstalling the packages solved the problem (after a reboot). Thanks.

Comment: Can you add a self-answer with the relevant package name? It could save others some time.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by searching through `/var/log/dpkg.log` for deleted or purged packages with `grep 'remove\|purge'  /var/log/dpkg.log | grep <date of purge>` .

Then installed missing packages with:

`sudo apt install plasma-pa libcanberra-pulse ubuntu-desktop-minimal ubuntu-desktop osspd-pulseaudio  pavucontrol-qt accountsservice-ubuntu-schemas xubuntu-desktop kubuntu-desktop osspd indicator-sound`

After a reboot everything went back to normal.